# Pivoting table gives error : Must declare the scalar variable @start1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Error :

> Must declare the scalar variable "@start1".

Here is my query, I have two functions and am trying to pivot the data. The first function `dbo.fxnExample` accepts parameters is good but the second function `dbo.fxnExample2` does not accept the parameters value, it pass 0 as the value.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SpTimesheetCrossTableFormat] 
@start NVARCHAR(20),
@end NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @start1 as nvarchar(20)=@start
    DECLARE @start2 as nvarchar(20)=@end
--Get DISTINCT values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @PivotColumnNames= convert(NVARCHAR(max),(ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','')))
+  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),(QUOTENAME(project_name)))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT project_name FROM dbo.fxnExample(@start,@end)) AS project_name 
--Get DISTINCT values of the PIVOT Column with isnull
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames 
    = ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')
    + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(project_name) + ', 0) AS '
    + QUOTENAME(project_name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT project_name FROM dbo.fxnExample(@start,@end)) AS project_name
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic

SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
N'SELECT d, user_name, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
FROM dbo.fxnExample2(@start1,@start2)
PIVOT(SUM(mins) 
FOR project_name IN (' + @PivotColumnNames + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
END
```

Here is the function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fxnExample2] (@StartDate NVARCHAR(20),@EndDate NVARCHAR(20))
RETURNS TABLE

AS

RETURN
(

SELECT user_details.user_name,project_details.name as project_name,
--(ISNULL( DATEDIFF(mi,convert(datetime,punch_in,108), CONVERT(datetime,punch_out,108)),0)) as mins
[hours] as  mins ,@StartDate as d
 FROM timesheets
JOIN user_details 
ON timesheets.user_id=user_details.id
JOIN project_details
ON timesheets.project_id=project_details.id
WHERE CONVERT(date, timesheets.tdate, 103)  BETWEEN CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 103)   and convert(date, @EndDate, 103) 
--where CONVERT(date, tdate, 103) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '15/08/2019', 103) AND CONVERT(date, '15/08/2019', 103)  

)`
```

`fnexample` function

```
`CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fxnExample] (@StartDate nvarchar(20),@EndDate nvarchar(20))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT user_details.user_name,project_details.name as project_name,
--(ISNULL( DATEDIFF(mi,CONVERT(datetime,punch_in,108), CONVERT(datetime,punch_out,108)),0)) as mins
[hours]  as mins
 FROM timesheets
JOIN user_details 
ON timesheets.user_id=user_details.id
JOIN project_details
ON timesheets.project_id=project_details.id
WHERE CONVERT(date, tdate, 103)  BETWEEN CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 103)   AND CONVERT(date, @EndDate, 103) 
--where CONVERT(date, tdate, 103)  BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '05/08/2020', 103)   AND CONVERT(date, '05/08/2019', 103)

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanations about your error:**

You are trying to execute a dynamic T-SQL statement using [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If this statement contains parameters, you need to pass definitions of these parameters and their values to `sp_executesql`.

In your case, execute your statement in the following way:

```
EXEC sp_executesql 
   @DynamicPivotQuery,
   N'@start1 as nvarchar(20), @start2 as nvarchar(20)',
   @start1,
   @start2
```

**Notes:**

It's good to check the result from `sp_executesql` call and optionally print this statement before the execution:

```
DECLARE @err int
PRINT @DynamicPivotQuery
EXEC @err = sp_executesql 
   @DynamicPivotQuery,
   N'@start1 as nvarchar(20), @start2 as nvarchar(20)',
   @start1,
   @start2
IF @err = 0 PRINT 'OK' ELSE PRINT 'Error'
```